# setInterval not working on calling php script

Tags: setinterval

Script:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){$('#container').load('includes/cashout_list.php')},5000);    
</script>
```

php file:

```
$query="Select * from cart";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if($result)
while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
{
    echo '<li>';
    echo $row["itemName"].'</li>';
}
```

the php script works fine but I cant call it from setInterval.

Comment: What happens? are you seeing any errors in your javascript console? My best guess is that  the script is being read before the DOM is created, so `#container` is not found by the script. You could put the script at the bottom of the page or within something like a `$(document).ready( function() { ... } )`

Comment: its just not refreshing div #container as its supposed to do,

Comment: it's probably the reason i mentioned.